# RandomForest.Writehdf5 gives boost.python argument mismatch errror

Tags: boost-python

I am new to python programming. When function Vigra.learning.RandomForest.Writehdf5 is called in the python code, it gives a error as below:

```
self.RF.writeHDF5(fileName, pathInFile, overwriteFlag)
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
RandomForest.writeHDF5(RandomForest, str, str, bool)
did not match C++ signature:
writeHDF5(class vigra::RandomForest<unsigned int,struct vigra::ClassificationTag>,          class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >   filename, class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > pathInFile='')
```

I have installed python extension package vigranumpy aswell as boost python but I have not installed vigra (c++ image processing lib ) . I am not able to trace the reason for the error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Boost.Python error indicates that the caller is trying to use a C++ signature of `RandomForest.writeHDF5(str, str, bool)` but the exported C++ function expects `RandomForest.writeHDF5(str, str)`.  I am not sure what behavior the `overwriteFlag` is intended to do, but changing:

```
self.RF.writeHDF5(fileName, pathInFile, overwriteFlag)
```

to

```
self.RF.writeHDF5(fileName, pathInFile)
```

should resolve the `Boost.Python.ArgumentError` exception.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, changing the parameters resolved the exception